# Lua table as frontend to database

Tags: lua, redis, lua-table

I am attempting to implement a database as a Lua table. Using metatables, this table would be empty, and when an item is requested or modified in the table, it would return or modify the item in the database. The database itself would never be loaded into memory, except for the parts which are requested. It should be interacted with by the program as a table (as it is a table). The table, since it's only a "front", would save modified data to the database (rather than defining that item in the table).

In a table with no tables inside of it, this is easy to implement. I'm trying to make it work with a multi-layered table of indefinite depth.
(Aside: The database I'm considering is redis. Ideally this could be implemented for any database or database-like server by only changing the basic operating syntax.)

Because of the behavior of Lua's metatables, the `__newindex` method is only used when something is modified in the top-level (or created, if you're using a proxy). The `__index` method is called when something is read, even if the call is to modify something within a sub-table. Because of this, I'm trying to write an `__index` method that, when a table is requested, returns yet another pseudo-proxy (a table proxying a database rather than another tables) with the same behavior, except the proxy is for the table/array/list within the top-level, etc, to an indefinite depth. I am struggling.

My questions are:

- Has this been implemented before?
- Should I be focusing on "proper"
  class system rather than what I'm doing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a table, simply add an empty table in the fake and set it's metatable:

```
local fake = {}
do
   local lookup = {} --Will be using this to avoid using lots of metatables

   local real = {}

   local meta
   meta = {
      __index = function(self,i)
         return rawget(lookup[self], i)
      end,
      __newindex = function(self,i,v)
         rawset(lookup[self], i, v)
         if type(v) == "table" then
             rawset(self, i, setmetatable({},meta))
             lookup[self[i]] = v
         end
      end
   }

   setmetatable(fake, meta)
   lookup[fake] = real
end

fake[1] = "hello"
print(fake[1])
print(rawget(fake, 1))
fake.x = {"hi"}
print(fake.x)
print(rawget(fake, 'x')) --This still prints a table because there actually is one, but in reality it's abiding by our rules
print(fake.x[1])
print(rawget(fake.x, 1))
fake.x.y = "aha"
print(fake.x.y)
print(rawget(fake.x, 'y'))
```

The only caveat with this method is they can directly modify the database like so:

```
fake.myvalue = {}
fake.myvalue = 5
```

Another method could be to wrap as you go:

```
local fake = {}
do
   local lookup = {} --Will be using this to avoid using lots of metatables
   local cache = {} --will be using to avoid usings tons of new objects

   local real = {}

   local meta
   meta = {
      __index = function(self,i)
         local val = rawget(lookup[self], i)
         if type(val) == "table" then
            if cache[val] then
                return cache[val]
            else
                local faker = {}
                lookup[faker] = val
                cache[val] = faker
                return setmetatable(faker, meta)
             end
         else
            return val
         end
       end,
      __newindex = function(self,i,v)
         rawset(lookup[self], i, v)
      end
   }

   setmetatable(fake, meta)
   lookup[fake] = real
end

fake[1] = "hello"
print(fake[1])
print(rawget(fake, 1))

fake.x = {"hi"}
print(fake.x)
print(rawget(fake, 'x')) --This still prints a table because there actually is one, but in reality it's abiding by our rules
print(fake.x[1])
print(rawget(fake.x, 1))
fake.x.y = "aha"
print(fake.x.y)
print(rawget(fake.x, 'y'))
```

Which avoids the direct modifying problem completely